# Show that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Define the function $f(x) = x\cdot\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ (where $\chi(x) = 1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\chi(x) = 0$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$. Show that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0$.

I tried solving this problem but I have no idea if I did it correctly. My professor mentioned something about functions like this oscillating too much to be continuous, so I figured it was okay to break this up into cases. Please let me know if this is wrong or if there are any errors, thanks!

Note that if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\chi(x) = 1$ and $2 > |\chi(x)|$. This implies,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{|\chi(x)|}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\epsilon}{2} < \frac{\epsilon}{|\chi(x)|}
\end{equation*}
So let $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then $0 < |x-0| < \delta$, implies
\begin{equation*}
|x - 0| < \delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \frac{\epsilon}{|\chi(x)|}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
|x||\chi(x)|  < \epsilon
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
|x\chi(x)|  < \epsilon
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
|x\chi(x) - 0|  < \epsilon
\end{equation*}

Note that if $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$, then $\chi(x) = 0$ and $|x||\chi(x)| < |x|$, because $x$ is converging to (and never equals) $0$.

Suppose $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$, and choose $\delta \leq \epsilon$. Then $0 < |x - 0| < \delta$ implies,
\begin{equation*}
0 = |x||\chi(x)| < |x| < \delta \leq \epsilon 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
|x\chi(x) - 0| < \epsilon
\end{equation*}

Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: You are thinking far too complicated. All you need is that $|f(x)| \le |x|$.

Comment: But am I right?

Comment: You are right. Actually the last $3$ lines of your proof from "Suppose $\epsilon...$" are sufficient. You do have to correct a small error: $|x||\chi(x)|\color{red}\le|x|$.

Comment: So I can think of a function as a sequence? One with rational terms and another with irrational terms(in this case)? I'm basically showing that subsequences converge, I think?.

Comment: In the last three lines, you are not restricting yourself to $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$. The proof is true in general. In the first part where your choice is $\delta\le\epsilon/2$, you have not considered any sequence but partitioned the $\delta$ neighbourhood of $0$ into rational and irrational points since the function takes different definitions for rational and irrational points. Then you have shown that $|f(x)-0|\le\epsilon$ for all points rational or irrational in the neighbourhood.

Comment: Oh, I see. I basically did what @Martin R said to do in those 3 lines. I think?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct.

Comment: I see. But it's still okay to use $\epsilon-N$, right?

Comment: Of course, no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Aware of the definition of the limit, ie you have to check that for any sequence $(x_n)_n$ converging to 0, the sequence $(f(x_n))_n$ converges to 0. so to be formally correct use this.
You’re idea is okay, but you have to put both together in the proof, so for $\epsilon >0$ let $\delta= \epsilon/2$ will do the job.
Another hint for a fast solution: remark that for any x we have $0 \leq |f(x)|\leq |x|$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct but you don't say what is your final choice of $\delta$ explicity. For $x\in\Bbb Q$, you chose $\delta\le\epsilon/2$ and for $x\in\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$, you chose $\delta\le\epsilon.$ So $\delta\le\epsilon/2$ works for both rational and irrational points in the $\delta$ neighbourhood of $0$.

Also note that for irrational points, we can infact choose any $\delta>0$ since $|f(x)|=0<\epsilon$ for all irrational points.

---

The last $3$ lines of your solution are sufficient proof if you make a small correction. For both rational and irrational $x, |f(x)|=|x\chi_{\Bbb Q}(x)|\le|x|$, so if we choose $\delta\le\epsilon$, then $0<|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|\color{red}\le|x|<\delta\le\epsilon$.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan That is for the OP to decide. The OP doesn't talk about sequences. It is not possible to prove continuity by examining all sequences in general. And please don't indulge in revenge downvoting.

Comment: Sure, but you haven't made any "comment on the quality of my answer".

Comment: What is "serious notational issues"?

Comment: So the other answer talks about "serious notational issues" in *my* answer? Great!